# MVC application authentication set to Windows. Httpcontext.current.user.identity.name empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-6

Scenario:

**IIS 6** - Anonymous is OFF and Integrated is ON.

**Web config of the App** - Authentication set to WINDOWS

**Users Network Computers** - We use a Common Access Card and a pin to login into our computers

Problem:

HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is always empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is IIS setup to support that Authentication?

Comment: Yes because on an older app that ran on that server, it was capturing the User. The only thing that has changed since then is the introduction of CAC cards with a pin. However, I do believe that authenticates against AD the same way.

Answer (score 0):

OK! Here is the answer. After sifting through the HttpContext object, I found the windows ID of the current user nested in the LogonUserIdentity child object.

HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name

Why the normal HttpContext.User object is not being set? I have no idea!

Anyway, problem solved!